# In PrimeNG, how do I bind checkboxes with the same name to a form control?

Tags: angular, forms, checkbox, primeng, form-control

I'm using PrimeNG 14 (and Angular 14).  I have a form in which I enter product information, and I would like to associate the product with one or more categories, each of which is displayed as a checkbox.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    ...
            <p-table #dt [value]="(categories$ | async)!" 
                [(selection)]="selectedCategories"
                dataKey="categoryId">

            <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <p-tableHeaderCheckbox></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
                    </th>
                    <th pSortableColumn="name">
                        <div>
                            Category
                            <p-sortIcon field="name"></p-sortIcon>
                            <p-columnFilter type="text" field="name" display="menu"></p-columnFilter>
                        </div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-category>
                <tr class="p-selectable-row">
                    <td>
                        <p-tableCheckbox [value]="category" [formControl]="$any(form.controls['categoryIds'])"></p-tableCheckbox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="p-column-title">Category</span>
                        {{category.name}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
             </ng-template>
        </p-table>
```

In my service class I have

```
  form!: FormGroup;
    ...

  ngOnInit(): void {
    ...
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      ...
      categoryIds: []
    });
```

The issue is, I'm not sure how to bind the category ID checkboxes to the form control.  Using the above approach doesn't work because when I check one checkbox, they all get checked.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide stackblitz for same?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-checkbox-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: A minimal working demo would work

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-checkbox-demo-bmt4dp?file=src/app/app.component.ts ?

Comment: Hi @Vikas, yes that is the general idea.  Only thing missing from that demo is there is no select/unselect all checkbox on the table, as is typically provided by the "p-tableHeaderCheckbox" component.

Answer (score 0):

`p-tableCheckbox` and `p-tableHeaderCheckbox` has there own logic which you can check [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/table/table.ts) and it doesn't seems to be working with formcontrol.Other way around is to build your own logic using `p-checkbox`.

In your component define `categoryIds` inside your form as form array and push formgroup inside the formarray for each category so your ts file will look like

```
form: FormGroup;
  isAllSelected:boolean=true;
  get formArr() {
    return this.form.get("categoryIds") as FormArray;
  }
  get isAllChecked(){
    return this.formArr.controls.every((fg:FormGroup)=> Object.keys(fg.controls).every(k=> fg.controls[k].value));
  }
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      isAllSelected:this.formBuilder.control(false),
      categoryIds: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });
    this.categories.forEach((c) => {
      let fg = this.formBuilder.group({});
      fg.addControl(c.key, this.formBuilder.control(false));
      this.formArr.push(fg);
    });
  }

  onRowSelectionChange(){
    this.form.get("isAllSelected").setValue(this.isAllChecked);
  }
  onAllSelectChange(e){
     this.formArr.controls.forEach((fg:FormGroup)=>{
      Object.keys(fg.controls).forEach(k=>{
        fg.controls[k].setValue(!!e.checked)
      })
     })
  }
```

On UI use `formarrayname` on tr and `formGroupName` on td and replace `p-tableCheckbox` and `p-tableHeaderCheckbox` with `p-checkbox`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="form">
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
            <p-table #dt [value]="categories" 
                [(selection)]="selectedCategories"
                dataKey="key"  >

            <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                      <p-checkbox formControlName="isAllSelected"  binary="true" (onChange)="onAllSelectChange($event)"></p-checkbox>
                    </th>
                    <th pSortableColumn="name">
                        <div>
                            Category
                            <p-sortIcon field="name"></p-sortIcon>
                            <p-columnFilter type="text" field="name" display="menu"></p-columnFilter>
                        </div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-category let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
                <tr class="p-selectable-row" formArrayName="categoryIds">
                  <td [formGroupName]="rowIndex">
                      <p-checkbox binary="true" [formControlName]="category.key" (onChange)="onRowSelectionChange()"></p-checkbox>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <span class="p-column-title">Category</span>
                      {{category.name}}
                  </td>
              </tr>
             </ng-template>
        </p-table>
  </form>
</ng-container>
```

Here is working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-checkbox-demo-2pdsgf?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Really appreciate your going the extra mile on this one.  Is the reason you included a link to the source code was to say PrimeNG has a bug that prevents binding to those elements, or rather to say this is not a feature that they support?  They don't seem to have anything in their open issues about this.

Comment: Actually there's another issue with this -- when you submit the form there is no form value with "categoryIds".  The reason this is important is I am deriving my object that I submit in my create (POST) request from this.form.value, and "categoryIds" is one of its attributes.

Comment: `this.form.value` currently returning a response like `{ "isAllSelected": false, "categoryIds": [ { "A": false }, { "M": false }, { "P": false }, { "R": false } ] }` you can modify it as per your model before posting it. If you can tell me the required output I can give you an example

Comment: On the feature side to me seems like its not supported they might not impalement the feature where it allows you to bind a formcontrol to tableHeaderCheckbox  or tableCheckbox  as i tried that and it didn't work

Comment: The thing I'm wrestling with regarding what you have is you created an arbitrary string data key for your category, but my category's data key was its ID, which is a number.  I'm discovering '[formControlName]="category.key"' doesn't work if the key is a number.  Also shoudn't the form control name be "categoryIds" to match the field of the form?  Anyway I'll experiment more.

Comment: changing the key on above example to number instead of string is also working. How can  we bind the formcontrol to a string i.e categoryIds when looping into an array?Even if you are able to bind it that will create the problem of checking all when you check one